# Is there any section wise cut-off for Salesforce pd1?

Tags: certification

[image]

My overall percentage is 68.5. but I have failed the pd1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the right answers to 39 questions out of 60([65%](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Salesforce-Certified-Platform-Developer-I-Exam-Guide) ) questions to pass.

Now section-wise cutoff might be a bit deceiving.

It rounds % up. If you answered 1 right out of 3 in a section, it doesnt give 33.33 it rounds to nearest Integer(upper bound/ceiling) 34.

So something similar happened here, 83, 87 seems rounded and gives you deceiving percentage.